# Ionic - Problems displaying AdMob banner/interstitial (iOS)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, admob

There are no issues what so ever showing both banner and interstitial ads on Android devices but on iOS devices they somehow don't show, only blank box in footer area and no popup appears - however works perfectly fine on the emulator, displaying test ads.

In AdMob - I have created only one app (iOS) and therefor only have two Ad Unit IDs(Banner and Interstitial) which I use, can that be the issue or ?

You can see my code below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig, AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

import { ProjectlistPage } from '../pages/projectlist/projectlist';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = ProjectlistPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private admobFree : AdMobFree) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      this.showAdmobBannerAds();
      this.showAdmobInterstitialAds();

    });
  }

  showAdmobBannerAds(){
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
        id: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxx', 
        isTesting: false,
        autoShow: true,

      };
    this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

    this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
    .then(() => {

        this.admobFree.banner.show();
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));    
    }


    showAdmobInterstitialAds(){
      const interstitialConfig: AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig = {
          id: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxx', 
          isTesting: false,
          autoShow: true,

        };
        this.admobFree.interstitial.config(interstitialConfig);

        this.admobFree.interstitial.prepare()
        .then(() => {
            this.admobFree.interstitial.show();
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));    
      } 
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved by adjusting payment details within AdMob to reflect 100% my companies DUNS info.

https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free/issues/157#issuecomment-374006844